# Should we also add that the "intertextuality" tag also indicates that a Question posting uses "Scripture interprets Scripture"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sorry, if I sound nit-picky when it come to details.  For the following "intertextuality" tag's definition. Should we also add that the "intertextuality" tag also indicates that a Question posting uses "Scripture interprets Scripture" ?

> [intertextuality]
>
> Intertextuality is the shaping of one text's meaning by another text.
> It is the interconnection between similar or related works of
> literature that reflect and influence an audience's interpretation of
> the text. Intertextual processes include allusion, quotation,
> plagiarism, translation and parody. (based on the Wikipedia
> definition)

Comment: No, because not everyone who uses the tag would necessarily think that.

Answer (score 4):

*Intertextuality* as you have observed is a **secular** principle, which could be applied to a wide range of texts and settings. It is basically a way of explicitly describing that there is an expected interrelationship between texts. Normally in hermeneutics we prize 'exegesis', reading meaning out of the text at hand, and that's our typical focus here on BH.SE.

*Scripture interprets scripture* is a **theistic** principle, where the *literary intent* is suggested to be such that a text *should* be read in light of other surrounding texts. There is a fluffy interrelationship between this concept and other theological concepts like the *inspiration* of Biblical texts, or further down the spectrum ideas like *inerrancy*.

### People handle these concepts differently

Ultimately the process of *exegesis* usually takes us away from these kinds of concepts - i.e. we try to avoid *injecting* modern concepts and principles into texts before deriving their meaning. However, there are a range of hermeneutical approaches (past and present), and there's no getting away from the fact that each of our approaches to passages will hinge on our attitude towards these theological principles.

The closer a **question** gets towards mandating one or more *theological principles* ahead of interpreting the passage, the more likely it is to be off-topic here. It's okay for individual users to supply answers that agree with a variety of theological stances on any issue (including the *Trinity*, *inerrancy* and others), but generally Questions shouldn't force users to go down one route or another - they should be focused on the *text* in its own intended context.

In essence, *intertextuality* is a valid exegetical principle, because it affirms that there is some sort of clear and valid link between the texts in front of us.

### Examples

As one good example, [Soldarnal once asked a good question about whether a passage in John is *intended* to evoke a passage in Leviticus](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48462/is-john-1030-intended-to-evoke-the-shema).

Similarly, [Michael once asked a question about an *intended link* between John and Ecclesiastes](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/40381/is-john-38-an-allusion-to-ecclesiastes-115). This is anchoring back on the core hermeneutical principle of *authorial intent* - **what did the author mean by what they said?**

[This question about Psalm 149](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/73578/psalm-1495-9s-indication-that-godly-ones-will-execute-vengeance-in-light-o) doesn't seem to quite apply it correctly:

*Psalm 149* was written a long time before *Romans*, and so it's incorrect to ask what the author meant as if they had Romans in front of them at the moment when they wrote it. Though on examination, Romans is actually quoting from Deuteronomy 32:35, so perhaps the reference just needs to be adjusted.

### Conclusion

Essentially the two principles are *similar*, but distinct. A question on *intertextuality* implies a link between passages that may/should affect the process of interpretation, whereas *scripture interprets scripture* affirms that one of the texts was *intended by the author* to be read in light of the other. So it's carrying an extra assumption into the text, if that helps disambiguate the concepts.

So, no - *intertextuality* is a fair and general hermeneutical tool, and doesn't risk or necessitate carrying theological baggage into the passage.